# MPI - Scaling for parallel drivers DOEDriver

Tags: openmdao

Have the parallel drivers been tested in terms of scaling by any developer/user ? What is the expected scaling for these?

I have a setup with openmpi and used the DOEDriver's parallel sample [from the manual](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/drivers/doe_driver.html) but with UniformGenerator.

Tested in 2,4,8,16 cores. The scaling performance is pretty bad. Is this due to 
a bottleneck that I am  not aware of in this example.

Do you have a better example proposals for testing scaling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, because you didn't give us any specifics about how you're running the example problems. I'll take a guess though that you just modified the basic example. Assuming that you are trying to run lots of cases of the [Paraboloid](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.5.0/basic_guide/first_analysis.html) model, based on [this specific example](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.5.0/basic_guide/first_analysis.html), then the problem you're seeing with scaling is likely due to the fact that the paraboloid model does not have significant computational cost to make parallelization worthwhile.

Any time you move from any algorithm or code from serial to parallel you always incur some amount of new overhead. Since OpenMDAO uses MPI based parallelism, there is now MPI communication overhead and additional framework level setup that needs to happen. Also, if you leave the default setup of that example problem, there is a recorder hooked up to the driver. When you run a DOE in parallel, then you get n different recorder files (one for each process you're using). So writing out results to each of those files takes time, and unless you have a parallel file system will add a bottleneck while the systems waits for the ability to write to disk.

So really, you need to be careful about parallelization, but here is a simple script to show that if you make the component calculations more expensive then you will get better scaling. This is not a rigorous scaling example, and the usage of the `sleep` function is a bit of a cheat because no real work is being done. But it gets the general point across.

```
import time


from openmdao.api import Problem, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent

from openmdao.api import DOEDriver, FullFactorialGenerator
from openmdao.api import SqliteRecorder, CaseReader

class Paraboloid(ExplicitComponent):
    """
    Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3.
    """

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0.0)

        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

        # Finite difference all partials.
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        """
        f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3

        Minimum at: x = 6.6667; y = -7.3333
        """
        x = inputs['x']
        y = inputs['y']

        outputs['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

        time.sleep(1)


prob = Problem()
model = prob.model

model.add_subsystem('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 0.0), promotes=['x'])
model.add_subsystem('p2', IndepVarComp('y', 0.0), promotes=['y'])
model.add_subsystem('comp', Paraboloid(), promotes=['x', 'y', 'f_xy'])

model.add_design_var('x', lower=0.0, upper=1.0)
model.add_design_var('y', lower=0.0, upper=1.0)
model.add_objective('f_xy')

prob.driver = DOEDriver(FullFactorialGenerator(levels=3))
prob.driver.options['run_parallel'] =  True
prob.driver.options['procs_per_model'] =  1
prob.driver.options['debug_print'] = ['desvars', 'objs']

prob.driver.add_recorder(SqliteRecorder("cases.sql"))

prob.setup()

st = time.time()
prob.run_driver()
print('time', time.time() - st)
```

**In summary:** 
You need your models/components to be sufficiently expensive to make parallelization worth while. If you're using file-wrapped components you need to be extra careful because all the file-i/o will be a huge bottle neck for a parallel execution.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to turn debug_print on for all cores. it seems that only rank 0 prints.